# Better performance after bios update?

Tags: performance, bios, updates

I updated my bios for my recently purchased laptop hp-ab048tx yesterday from Insyde F.03 (03-15-15) to F.81 (07-25-16). While the changelog for this and the previous version didn't list much other than fixing intermittent crashes (which I didn't have), apparently the performance has actually improved, especially the boot times. Earlier, a restart used to take much longer, but now it seems almost as fast as a startup after shutting down (I'm using Windows 10's fast startup). Is this possible (bios update increasing performance) or just the placebo effect?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its possible the current or previous versions including performance enhancements that were not listed.  Or perhaps the code that fixed the intermittent crashes was causing a slowdown.  There is no way to know, however you say there is a visible improvement, so more than likely some changed increased the performance.

Comment: Great! I have been told before that bios updates simply 'cannot' increase performance, so I was thinking it must be just me being too optimistic.

Comment: bios updates absolutely can increase performance